# Function returns always Boolean False

Tags: vba, excel

I have following function:

```
Function IsInArray(ByVal needle As String, haystack() As String) As Boolean
  Dim element As Variant
  For Each element In haystack
    If element = needle Then
      IsInArray = True
    End If
  Next element
  IsInArray = False
End Function
```

Which I'm calling via this subroutine:

```
Sub CallIsInArray()
  Dim haystack(1 To 4) As String
  haystack(1) = "T1"
  haystack(2) = "T2"
  haystack(3) = "T3"
  haystack(4) = "T4"

  Dim needle As String
  needle = "T1"  ' Should return True but instead of it return False
  ' needle = "T1x" ' Return False as expected

  Dim result As Boolean
  result = IsInArray(needle, haystack)
  MsgBox result
End Sub
```

The problem is that `IsInArray` always return `False`, why?

Comment: It's true on the first pass but you continue through the array. You need to break out if there is a match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to return (`Exit Function`) when you find the `needle`.

```
Function IsInArray(ByVal needle As String, haystack() As String) As Boolean
  Dim element As Variant
  For Each element In haystack
    If element = needle Then
      IsInArray = True
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next element
  IsInArray = False
End Function
```